# How to separate items from array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, redux, react-redux

I'm making weather app for 7 days and I need to create abillity for users to open some of days to see more information about weather of current day. So, it means that every item choosen by user has to contain unique id (i don't know could I use in this situation index instead of id) to show information only about some of day. So before this I had some code:

```
const DailyWeatherData = ({dailyData, isLoading}) => {

    const getWeatherStatistic = (value0,value1) => {
        if(dailyData && Array.isArray(dailyData.daily)){
            return (
                <div className="col-lg-3 box-daily-weather">
                    <NavLink to={'/WeatherDayStat'}>
                        {setDay([value1])}
                        <div className="temp-day">{Math.ceil(dailyData.daily[value0].temp.day)}°C</div>
                        <div className="feels-like">Feels like: {Math.ceil(dailyData.daily[value0].feels_like.day)}°C</div>
                        <div className="daily-weather-condition">Conditions: {dailyData.daily[value0].weather.map(e => e.main)}</div>
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
            )
        }else {
            return isLoading === true ? <Preloader /> : null
        }
    }

    const setDay = (param) => {
        return checkCod ? null : setCurrentDate(new Date(),param)
    }

    return ( 
        <div> 
            <div className="daily-weather-container">
                {checkCod ? null : <div className="daily-title">Daily Weather</div>}
                <div className='row scrolling-wrapper justify-content-center'>
                    {getWeatherStatistic(1,1)}
                    {getWeatherStatistic(2,2)}
                    {getWeatherStatistic(3,3)}
                    {getWeatherStatistic(4,4)}
                    {getWeatherStatistic(5,5)}
                    {getWeatherStatistic(6,6)}
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default DailyWeatherData
```

In function `getWeatherStatistic` you can see 2 arguments, `value0` - doesn't matter here, `value1` - using to show only 1st-6 object, because array which i have got from ajax request contains more days(10) but I need to show only 6 of them. And most importantly, each of them is separate. Logically I'd use `map`, but It shows all items, so I can use `slice` but it also shows 6 items in 1 column.

The next problem, this array has not contain parameter like `ID`, that's why I can't add to `NavLink` `id`. If there were ID, I would make something like that `dailyData.daily.map(p => <NavLink to={'/WeatherDayStat' + p.id}>)`

---

Also, just in case, add the state code (`daily` - array which I need):

[image]

---

So I have 2 questions:

1. How to show only 6 days from array?
2. How to add unique ID to every Item from array?

Comment: you should not be calling your get getWeatherStatistic. 6x, use a map, also your arg1 and arg2 don't make sense since they are the same use one arg

Comment: @EugenSunic array which i have got from ajax request contains more days(10) but I need to show only 6 of them. And most importantly, each of them is separate. Logically I'd use map, but It shows all items, so I can use slice but it also shows 6 items in 1 column.

Comment: @EugenSunic array - 10 objects; I have to show only 6 objects of them and every of them has to get the same HTML structure (to separate on 6 columns)

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice` is the correct way to get a partial copy of an array. I'm not sure what you mean by "it shows 6 items in 1 column", but you might need to manually add each item from the array to it's own column (eg in a for...of loop.)
As for your id, I wouldn't do this in production, but you could use the timestamp (`dt`). This will be unique only until you send another request for weather using that  exact time, at  which point you'd end up with duplicate id values (which is bad.) Alternatively, you could put a counter somewhere in your app use it to get a new integer for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making something like this:

```
//making new array with data I need
let sliceDailyData = dailyData.daily ? dailyData.daily.slice(1,7) : null

//using map with new array
 {sliceDailyData ? sliceDailyData.map((i) => <div key={i.dt} className="col-lg-3 box-daily-weather">
                            {getCurrentDate(new Date())}
                            <NavLink to={'/WeatherDayStat'}>
                                <div className="temp-day">{Math.ceil(i.temp.day)}°C</div>
                                <div className="feels-like">Feels like: {Math.ceil(i.feels_like.day)} °C</div>
                                <div className="daily-weather-condition">Conditions: {i.weather.map(i => i.main)} </div>
                            </NavLink>
                        </div>
                   ): null}
```

Speaking about ID, I have created variable which generte id and push it to array.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your `dailyData.daily` array in an object and then retrieve it with key, you can use something simple but SEO friendly like `obj['day'+(dailyData.daily.indexOf(d)+1)]`

```
obj{}
dailyData.daily.forEach(d=>array.indexOf(d)<=5?obj[String(Math.random())]=d:null)
```